OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE doesn't work ROOM
I have a problem, when i insert a new element to the table it gives me an exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: DayCalorieData.date (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY), but i dont't uderstand why. Because i set OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE. Here is code for my db:
Entity:
@Entity(
    tableName = "dayNutrientAmount",
    primaryKeys = ["date", "nutrientId"],
    indices = [Index(value = ["date", "nutrientId"], unique = true)]
)
data class DayNutrientAmount(
    val date: String,
    val nutrientId: Int,
    val receivedAmount: Int = 0,
)

Dao:
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insertNewDayNutrient(dayNutrientAmount: DayNutrientAmount)

ViewModel:
fun insertNewDayNutrientAmount(nutrientId: Int, date: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        mainScreensRepositoryImpl.insertDayNutrientAmount(DayNutrientAmount(
            date, nutrientId
        ))
    }
}

Ui:
val nutrients = homeScreenVM
    .getAllNutrients()
    .collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    .value
LaunchedEffect(key1 = nutrients, key2 = selectedDate) {
    nutrients.forEach { nutrient ->
        homeScreenVM.insertNewDayNutrientAmount(nutrient.nutrientId, selectedDate)
    }
}

I don't think that viewModel code and ui code are needed for understanding. But i left it just in case
I need an unique combination of date and nutrientId, and they don't have to be primary keys. I tried to add simple key for every row(just an integer id) instead of make nutrientId and date primary keys. But result was the same. Thank you in advance

I cannot reproduce the problem, it works as expected. You can verify that by creating a new project with just the code provided here. You can then compare the differences between your actual (not working) code and the example code to narrow it down where error actually is.

@Leviathan, yes the code is normal, i just restarted android studio, get a little rest and it works). I don't know how, i didn't change anything, it's just work)

Not that it is the issue but there is no need for, and it would be inefficient, the 2 unique indexes on the same columns (i.e. a Primary Key is implicitly UNIQUE see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#the_primary_key) so you may wish to just have @Entity(tableName = "dayNutrientAmount", primaryKeys = ["date", "nutrientId"]) ....
